# Variable expansion in Makefiles

Tags: makefile, variable-expansion

Make seems to be expanding variables only **after** a rule is active.

`make ok` displays the resolved NAME (ie. "test")

`make bad` claims to depend on "grep" (rather than "test")

How can I get `make` to expand NAME **before** it checks the dependencies of the "bad" rule?

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
add_executable(test testA.c testB.c)  # compiler (output input input ...)
```

**Makefile (full):**

```
#========================================
# Shell cannot handle parentheses:
#    *** unterminated call to function 'shell': missing ')'.  Stop.
# Have also tried putting {"(", ")", "\(", "\)"} in variables
#   ...but it just created a different problem
#
#NAME := $(shell grep "add_executable(" CMakeLists.txt | sed 's/[^(]*( *\([^ ]*\) .*/\1/')
  
#========================================
# Curious results (same with or without the colon)
#
NAME := `grep "add_executable(" CMakeLists.txt | sed 's/[^(]*( *\([^ ]*\) .*/\1/'`
    
#========================================
# As expected, displays:
#    NAME=¦test¦"
#
PHONY: ok
ok:
    @echo "NAME=¦${NAME}¦"
 
#========================================
# Dies with:
#    *** No rule to make target '`grep', needed by 'bad'.  Stop."
#
.PHONY: bad
bad: ${NAME}
    @echo "NAME=¦${NAME}¦"
```

**Makefile (same, but condensed):**

```
NAME := `grep "add_executable(" CMakeLists.txt | sed 's/[^(]*( *\([^ ]*\) .*/\1/'`
ok:
    @echo "NAME=¦${NAME}¦"
bad: ${NAME}
    @echo "NAME=¦${NAME}¦"
```

Comment: Here is a crude solution that will work until I (or someone) can figure out a more elegant one: `NAME := $(shell sed -n "/add_executable/{s/add_executable. *//;s/ .*//;p;}" CMakeLists.txt)
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of backquotes, use [the `shell` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Shell-Function):

```
NAME := ${shell sed -n '/add_executable/{s/add_executable( *//;s/ .*//;p;}' CMakeLists.txt}
```

(This use of curly braces instead of parentheses around the `shell` command is a kludge to allow a parenthesis in the `sed` command, which I don't know how to escape elegantly.)

Comment: Extra kudos for showing me how to clean up the `grep|sed` :) Thank you.